# Android Wi-Fi check request in local network

Tags: android, request, broadcastreceiver, wifi

Is it possible in Android, when phone in local network with router, send from notebook request with simple request (for example - http://192.168.15.1/par-1). I need get this request when it comes maybe in my OnReceive method in BroadcastReceiver. 
EDIT: I have a local network - one router, one notebook (windows) and one phone (android). I need, when from notebook in browser i enter - http://192.168.15.1/par-1, in my phone, my broadcast receiver notify me that somebody made request to it.

Comment: No in Android its not possible to send request from notebook. There is no Android for notebooks.

Comment: @greenapps  Sorry for my english. I don't mean notebook in Android. I mean there is local network with notebook and phone (in Android) in. And i want, to have listener over wi-fi network, that doing next: When, for example, in notebook in browser i enter something like  http://192.168.15.1/par-1, my broadcast receiver check it?

Comment: Please edit your post. Explain what you want there. Not in comments.